# How to set default value in wpf binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a textbox that binds to a property (CustomerId with datatype of int). this textbox at first shows a 0 (zero), but i want a clear textbox with no input at first.

i also set its default value to null like the below code:

```
ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value",
            typeof(int?), typeof(ChooseCustomerControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: How is `CustomerId` related to `Value`? Are we talking about the same property?

Comment: Value={Binding Path=CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

Comment: But you say that you have a "textbox that binds to a property CustomerId". Then i guess that you bind `TextBox.Text`. So what is `Value` for?

Comment: Or is `Value` perhaps a property of a derived TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change datatype of CustomerId from int to int?.

If you can't do that, create  [converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) , which transform CustomerId (int) to wanted value.